# MySQL WHERE query - meet some of these criteria

Tags: mysql

I have a table with multiple fields and would like to do a search where the query meets a set number e.g. satisfy 3 of 4 search criteria (`A` = 'red' OR `B` = 'red' OR `C` = 'Red' OR `D`='Red'). Is there an easy way to do this when the fields are in the same table?

As an aside, I have a second table (with multiple rows of matching data) which I join onto the first that I can perform this operation on by counting the number of rows joined and insisting the count is above 3 (in the example above) but when the fields are all in one table I am not sure it can be done.

Comment: What issue you are getting if using OR condition as you mentioned.

Comment: I need to be able to get the query to only show results that meet 3 of the 4 criteria the OR statement would allow results to show that only meet a single criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly:

You want to select these rows that match a particular number of these "OR"-combined parts, correct? One possible solution: every comparison returns either a 1 (if the result was true) or a 0 (if the result was false). You can just add the results of the comparisons and compare this integer against you desired threshold:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  mytable
WHERE
  ((A IN ('FOO','BAR')) + (B IN ('A','B','C')) + (C IN ('USA','MEX'))) > 2
```

Comment: That is what I need and I have used the MySQL: SELECT  *
FROM test
WHERE
  (`Season` IN ('Winter','Spring') + `Numbercode` IN ('500','20') + `OriginCountry` IN ('USA','MEX')) > 2                                                       but I get an error:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ `Numbercode` IN ('500','20') + `OriginCountry` IN ('USA','MEX')) > 2 LIMIT 0,' at line 6

Comment: Ah sorry, I found it: you have to add parenthesis around each IN statement. I fixed the query in the answer.

Comment: That's working great thank you. That's the bit I was struggling with now to integrate it with the second table .....

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
select * from mytable where 'RED' IN(A, B, C, D);
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/366bf8/1)**

**EDIT:**

However if you want to search for multiple distinguished query like what you have said in comments:

```
A in ('Red', 'Blue') 
OR B = 'Tall' 
OR C IN ( '1', '2','3') 
OR D IN ('USA','CAN','MEX')
```

Then there is no shorter way to write it. You have to use the same query to match the values.

Comment: @ZafarMalik:- Yes and that is what OP wants.!

Comment: OK sorry, my example was a little to simplistic as the query would be more along the lines (`A` in ('Red', 'Blue') OR `B` = 'Tall'  OR `C` IN ( '1', 2','3') OR `D` IN ('USA','CAN','MEX').

Comment: Although its useful to know that you can use the IN statement in that manner, thanks.

Comment: @rsphorler:- Then you have to use the `OR` statement as you are writing presently. You cannot make it short.

Comment: But is there a way to make it have to meet at least 3 of the 4 listed criteria?

Comment: @rsphorler:- You can check like `A in (('Red', 'Blue') 
OR B = 'Tall' 
OR C IN ( '1', '2','3') 
OR D IN ('USA','CAN','MEX')) >= 3`